# Is there a way to delete a test wallet without stopping bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoind, wallet, testnet, testing

For my unit tests, I'd like to be able to delete and recreate a wallet without having to stop `bitcoind` and manually deleting the wallet directory.

When I try to delete such wallet directory without stopping `bitcoind`, I get an error since an handle exists on "`db.log`" (on Windows at least).

Is there a clean way to delete a (testnet) wallet without stopping `bitcoind`?

Comment: Why are you using testnet? Regtest mode exists explicitly for that purpose.

Comment: Would `bitcoind` really allow me to delete a wallet when running on regtest? For some reason I doubt it would make any difference... I guess I should try!

Comment: Why do you want to? You can just restart the node.

Comment: That is exactly what I try to avoid and why I ask this question in the first place! :-)

Comment: You seem to be very confused i to believing that restarting a node during a unit test is somehow bad or abnormal.

Comment: Well, recreating a wallet would make way more sense in my case and would be way faster (even if I'm sure the regTest node is faster to restart than a testnet one). I guess I'll indeed have to restart the node, if wallets can't be deleted otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: It takes seconds to restart a regtest node. Faster than whining on stack exhange about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unload the wallet using `unloadwallet` and then delete the wallet file.